# Line numbers in dotnet-stack report

Tags: .net-core

With `dotnet-stack report -p <pid>` I can see the stack traces, but I don't see the line numbers. Is it possible to display line numbers (like `jstack` does)? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following properties to `csproj` files:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>

    <!-- The following is to fix error line numbers mismatch -->
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
```